# How to configure SSH private key for Fork on Mac?

Tags: git, git-fork-client

I prefer Fork's GUI, but seems unlike other Git client software which we can specify the path of our own SSH keys!

Neither Preference nor Clone on Fork's menu, I cannot find where/how to specify SSH private keys!
Can someone let me what/how to do in detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Generate a key and set up `~/.ssh/config` file

```
Host github_for_fork
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_new_id_rsa
  HostName github.com
```

2. Then when cloning repo - use the host alias that you configured in config: `git clone git@github_for_fork:org/repo.git`

PS: I haven't worked with Fork per se, but usually that's the algorithm.

Comment: If you add `User git`, then you can just leave off the `git@`.  And he probably already has a key that's registered with GitHub, so likely doesn't need to generate another and should just reference his existing key.  Finally, I generally shorten this to `Host gh`, so I only have to type `git clone gh:org/repo.git`. :-)

Comment: I had to open Fork > Configure SSH Keys and uncheck all keys after this setup.

Answer (score 6):

With Fork, you can go to Fork -> Configure SSH Keys option, then select the SSH key that you desire in the dialog box.

This seems to be a new feature in Fork 2.5

[image]